# Random Choice: List Format & Minimizing Memory Use

Tags: performance-tuning, random, memory

This is a two part question, and for that I apologize.. but they're related!

Here's what I'm working with:

```
d1 = Import["file.CSV", "List"]

size = Length[d1]

dis1 = RandomChoice[{d1}, {100, size}]
```

- **Q1**: Length views `d1` as $300,000$ individual elements but `RandomChoice` views it as a single element. Thus when I execute I get $100$ repetitions of `d1` in the exact order `d1` is presented in.

  Have I made an annotation error in assigning the `RandomChoice` number pool as `{d1}`? If I replace `{d1}` with a hand written list of values it executes perfectly, so I assume it is a presentation issue.. but I can't tell what I've done wrong from the documentation of the function.
- **Q2**: Asking to make $100$ random lists of `size` ~ $300,000$ elements requires a lot of memory. The thing is I don't need to save each `RandomChoice` output, I just need the mean/median/SD/SEM for each of the $100$ sets I've tasked `RandomChoice` with.

  Is there a way to tell the program to spit out those end-point values and dump the accumulated list after each one is generated?

Answer (score 4):

Q1: You don't need the curly-braces around `d1` in the `RandomChoice`: That turns it into a list with one element - `d1`.

Q2: If memory utilization is more important than speed (because it is usually far better to generate samples/variates/etc. *en masse*), you can do something like this:

```
myBigList = RandomInteger[100, 20000];
listLen = Length[myBigList];

results = 
 Reap[Do[picks = RandomChoice[myBigList, listLen]; 
    Sow[{Mean[#], Median[#], StandardDeviation[#]} &@picks], {100}]][[2,
    1]]
```

(Replace my `RandomInteger` with your import).

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much for both answers.

The Reap/Sow usage is excellent. And yes, memory is more important currently. I'll be iterating this procedure quite a lot.

Comment: A follow up query.. if anyone has input. Let's say instead of Sowing the Mean/Median/SD I directly take #1 and #2 lists from "picks" and perform a T-test on those and punch out the p-value, then repeat for the next 2 randomchoice sets. Is that possible? I didn't realize Mathematica would compute p-values for whole data sets.

Comment: @justin: Sure. Just replace `listLen` in the `RandomChoice` with `{2,listLen}`, and the whole `{Mean[#], Median[#], StandardDeviation[#]} &` part with `TTest` and you're set. Note that you'll get results for *pairs* of sampled lists, so adjust the iterator if needed.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it! I gave that a whirl but was coming up with very large p-values. I suspect the default of TTest is to compare the query set to 0. I made an attempt to recode as follows:

`results =
 Reap[Do[pick1 = RandomChoice[d1, {1, listLen}]; 
    pick2 = RandomChoice[d1, {1, listLen}];
    Sow[{TTest[pick1, pick2 , "PValue"]}], {1}]][[2, 1]]`

The goal being to generate the first list as the query set, and the second list as the comparison set. But it keeps telling me my array is the wrong size/shape.

Thanks for the input folks!

Comment: @Justin: take the `{1,listLen}` to just `listLen` - the way you have it written, you're asking for a list of one element that is a list of `listLen` choices. You'll also then need to bracket the `pick1` and `pick2` in the `TTest`. There's no real need to pick these separately though, since `TTest` does not "favor" either list - it simply compares if the means are the same, so doing it as I showed is (a bit) faster.

Comment: To clarify.. here's what I'm plugging in now. I was concerned that RandomChoice was only producing 1 list to perform the T-test on so I requested it generate 2 lists prior to the Sow step. Is this.. a correct way to generate a TTest comparison of the 2 lists?
`d1 = Import[
   "data", "List"];

listLen = Length[d1]
teststat = Mean[d1]
RandomSeed[AbsoluteTime[DateString[]]]

results =
 Reap[Do[picks = RandomChoice[d1, {2, listLen}];
      Sow[TTest@picks], {50}]][[2, 1]]`

Comment: I assume some semi-colons/line-breaks are in there - yes, that's fine. No real need for `RandomSeed` here (and assume you meant `SeedRandom`), that's normally used with some fixed seed to generate the same stream of variates (say for testing).

Answer (score 0):

For Q1, your syntax mistake is an extra pair of brackets. The following code should work properly:

```
d1 = Import["file.CSV", "List"]
size = Length[d1]
dis1 = RandomChoice[d1, {100, size}]
```